# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'map'

Tags: stable-diffusion

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'map'`

I don't know shape of tensorflow datasets. So might be it's not compatible with my own datasets.

i got the code from KERAS https://keras.io/examples/generative/ddpm/.
i want to use own datasets instead load oxford_flowers102 from tensorflow datasets.

```
dataset_name = "oxford_flowers102"
splits = ["train"]
```

## Load the dataset

(ds,) = tfds.load(dataset_name, split=splits, with_info=False, shuffle_files=True)`

My datasets was 100 images with 2 clases, and saved in my gDrive, and i want split with sklearn library

```
print('X Train ; ', len(X_train))
print(X_train.shape)
print('X Test ; ', len(X_test))
print(X_test.shape)
print('..............')

print('Y Train ; ', len(y_train))
print(y_train.shape)
print('Y Test ; ', len(y_test))
print(y_test.shape)
```

X Train ;  766
(766, 224, 224, 3)
X Test ;  256
(256, 224, 224, 3)
..............
Y Train ;  766
(766,)
Y Test ;  256
(256,)

i got error when :

```
train_ds = (
    X_train.map(train_preprocessing, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
    .batch(batch_size, drop_remainder=True)
    .shuffle(batch_size * 2)
    .prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
)
```

`      1 train_ds = (
----> 2     X_train.map(train_preprocessing, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
3     .batch(batch_size, drop_remainder=True)
4     .shuffle(batch_size * 2)
5     .prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'map'`

I don't know shape of tensorflow datasets. So might be it's not compatible with my own datasets.